# determine equal-tail credible interval

Tags: r, bayesian, credible-interval

[image]

I have obtained the posterior density for part d: $2 theta^{-1}(1- theta)^{-1}$. How do I plot in R the distribution to find the l and u such that $F_{theta| x} (l) = 0.025$ and $F_{theta| x} (u) = 0.975$? (the equal-tail interval)

Comment: You certainly did a mistake : your posterior is *improper*, that is, its integral is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is erroneous. By Bayes' theorem, the posterior density is proportional to **p(theta)P(X=2|theta) = 1-theta**. So we recognize the Beta distribution **Beta(1,2)**. To graph it in R, you can do:

```
curve(dbeta(x, 1, 2), from = 0, to = 1)
```

Now the posterior equi-tailed credible interval is given by the quantiles of this distribution. In R:

```
qbeta(0.025, 1, 2) # lower bound
qbeta(0.975, 1, 2) # upper bound
```

If you don't know the Beta distribution, you can get these quantiles by elementary calculations. The integral of **1-theta** on **[0,1]** is **1/2**. So the posterior density is **2(1-theta)** (it must integrate to one). So the posterior cumulative distribution function is **2(theta - theta²/2) = -theta² + 2theta**. To get the p-quantile (with p=0.025 and p=0.975), you have to solve the equation **-theta² + 2theta = p** in **theta**. This a second-degree polynomial equation, easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the central 95% CI is actually easier than finding the 95% HPD.  As you have the density (PDF), you also know the CDF.  The lower and upper limits of the central 95% CI are given by CDF(l) = 0.025 and CRF(u) = 0.975.